# FFMPEG add concat into lavfi

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming, audio-streaming

This is my code:

```
VBR="1500k"
FPS="25"
QUAL="superfast"

YOUTUBE_URL="rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2"
KEY=""

VIDEO_SOURCE="0005.mp4"
AUDIO_SOURCE="radio.mp3"
NP_SOURCE="song.txt"
FONT="dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf"

ffmpeg \
    -re -f lavfi -i "movie=filename=$VIDEO_SOURCE:loop=0, setpts=N/(FRAME_RATE*TB)" \
    -thread_queue_size 512 -i "$AUDIO_SOURCE" \
    -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 \
    -map_metadata:g 1:g \
    -vf drawtext="fontsize=20: fontfile=$FONT: \
        box=0: boxcolor=black@0.5: boxborderw=20: \
        textfile=$NP_SOURCE: reload=1: fontcolor=white@0.8: x=50: y=th" \
    -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset $QUAL -r $FPS -g $(($FPS * 2)) -b:v $VBR \
    -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -threads 6 -b:a 320k -bufsize 512k \
    -f flv "$YOUTUBE_URL/$KEY"
```

I'm trying to add something similar to

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop 1 -safe 0 -i mylist.txt
```

but the VIDEO_SOURCE doesn't recognize the txt file. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The movie filter args should be

```
movie=filename=$VIDEO_SOURCE:loop=0:f=concat
```

---

But why? the movie filter doesn't allow you to set options for the input demuxer. More flexible to read it as a regular input and add stream_loop.

`ffmpeg -f concat -re -stream_loop 1 -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -vf setpts=N/(FRAME_RATE*TB),drawtext=...`

Comment: How would I add the regular input and then make it so that lavfi is effecting it?

Comment: And this is the output after adding :f=concat

`[concat @ 0x55ef45aa4800] Unsafe file name '/video/0013.mp4'
[Parsed_movie_0 @ 0x55ef45aa3c00] Failed to avformat_open_input 'playlist.txt'
[lavfi @ 0x55ef45aa27c0] Error initializing filter 'movie' with args 'filename=playlist.txt:loop=0:f=concat'
movie=filename=playlist.txt:loop=0:f=concat, setpts=N/(FRAME_RATE*TB): Operation not permitted` 
@gyan

Comment: Like I mentioned in my answer, the movie filter doesn't allow you to set options for the input demuxer. If you move or link all files in the concat list to working directory. it may work.

Comment: See edit for normal input usage.

Comment: Problem with -stream_loop 1 and a .txt is it doesn't actually loop the file though. I see there are some hacks around it on the ffmpeg site but is it still better to use it?

Comment: You'll need ffmpeg 4.1 or later for stream_loop, and it should be `-stream_loop -1`

Comment: I must have looked at this a hundred times last night and read -1 only to actually have 1 in the code. Thank you very much Gyan sensei! I appreciate all the time you take to answer my noob questions.